# Redirect to a specific page when WooCommerce product search returns "no product found"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, code-snippets, wordpress-shortcode

In Woocommerce I am trying to use the following code snippet to redirect to a specific page of my site instead of showing "no result found" on an empty product search.

Now the shortcode `[insert page id="99"]` doesn't work, and displays `[insert page id="99"]` as plain text. **If I use shortcode any shortcode like** `'[recent_products per_page="4"]'` it displays products.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_no_products_found', 'wc_no_products_found' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_no_products_found', 'show_products_on_no_products_found', 20 );
function show_products_on_no_products_found() {
    echo '<h4>' . __( 'Are u looking for this?', 'domain' ) . '</h4>';
    echo do_shortcode( '[insert page id="99"]' );
}
```

But I want is to redirect to a specific WordPress page which post id is 99.

How to redirect user to a specific page when a product search returns "no product found"?

Comment: What's the code for your shortcode? `[insert page]` is not a [WC Shortcode][ https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-product-search/shortcodes/

Comment: found it in a forum,i thought its default shortcode for worpdress pages,can you tell me the shortcode for wordpress page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `template_redirect` hook, you can redirect user to a specific page when there is "no results found" on a product query search, like:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'no_products_found_redirect' );
function no_products_found_redirect() {
    global $wp_query; 
    if( isset($_GET['s']) && isset($_GET['post_type']) && 'product' === $_GET['post_type'] 
    && ! empty($wp_query) && $wp_query->post_count == 0 ) {
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( 99 ) );
        exit();
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: it worked !!! , thank you taking time to solve my issue.